# iterate over unknown number of properties using ant and search and replace

Tags: ant

I have an ant "properties" file that looks like this (although I can adjust the format if needed - I can make it an XML file if that's more appropriate):

**libraries.properties**

```
name 1
http://www.url1.com?a=b
name 2
http://www.url2.com?c=d
name 3
http://www.url3.com?e=f
```

NOTE: I know this is not a valid properties format because it's not in the form a=b. I can change it to anything that's appropriate, as long as it's easy to add entries in future.

I want ant to take a file that is checked-in as follows:

**options.html (source)**

```
<select>
    <option value="@URL@">@NAME@</option>
</select>
```

... and do a search and replace on the tokens *as many times as there are name/value entries* in libraries.properties, so the resulting options.html file would look like this:

**options.html (after build)**

```
<select>
    <option value="http://www.url1.com?a=b">name 1</option>
    <option value="http://www.url2.com?c=d">name 2</option>
    <option value="http://www.url3.com?3=f">name 3</option>
</select>
```

As with the properties file, the options.html source can be a different format. I just need some way of defining what I copy from/to.

What's the cleanest way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need is a [templating engine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_engine_%28web%29) to generate your HTML file.

The closest thing to this that ANT directly supports is an [XSLT transformation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XSLT).

## Example

The following project

```
|-- build.xml
`-- src
    |-- options.xsl
    `-- properties.xml
```

When run generates a single HTML file

```
|-- build
|   `-- options.html
```

Note, this is not a properly formatted HTML file. Your specification looks more like a fragment designed to be imported into another file.

### properties.xml

```
<properties>
    <property>
        <name>name 1</name>
        <value>http://www.url1.com?a=b</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>name 2</name>
        <value>http://www.url2.com?c=d</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>name 3</name>
        <value>http://www.url3.com?e=f</value>
    </property>
</properties>
```

### options.xsl

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:output method="html"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <select>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="properties/property"/>
        </select>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="property">
        <option value="{value}"><xsl:value-of select="name"/></option>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

### build.xml

```
<project name="demo" default="generate">

    <target name="init">
        <mkdir dir="build"/>
    </target>

    <target name="generate" depends="init">
        <xslt style="src/options.xsl" in="src/properties.xml" out="build/options.html"/>
    </target>

    <target name="clean">
        <delete dir="build"/>
    </target>

</project>
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed suggestion. It works perfectly, and is much more elegant than the kludge that I had implemented after posting my question. (I added a marker to my destination file, then searched-and-replaced multiple times to build up the list of options).